# Cubic radical extension

Tags: galois-theory, extension-field

I have the answer to this question but I can't understand a part of it. This is the first thing in the exercise:

> Let $K$ be a field in $\mathbb{C}$ and $p(x)=x^3+px+q$ a irreducible polynomial in $K[x]$. Consider $x$ a root of $p(x)$ and $D=d^2=-4p^3-27q^2$ the discriminant of $p(x)$.
> Take an $u=a+bx+cx^2$ of $K(x)$ that it is not in $K$, with minimal polynomial $x^3+a'x^2+b'x+c'$ in $K$.
> Determine $a'$ and $b'$ in terms of $a, b, c, p, q$.

This part is OK, I did it and undertand it, than there's this:

> Show that $K(x)$ is a radical extension of $K$ if and only if $-3D$ is a square in $K$.

The answer I have is this:

> So that $K(x)$ is a radical extension of $K$, it is necessary and sufficient that exists an element $u=a+bx+cx^2\in K(x)$ such that $K(x)=K(u)$, $u^3\in K$.

And that is the part I don't get, how do I prove that if $K(x)$ is a radical extension then exists an element $u=a+bx+cx^2\in K(x)$ such that $K(x)=K(u)$, $u^3\in K$, the more confusing part for me is the $u^3\in K$.

Comment: Radical extensions are defined in that manner. So what you seek is an immediate consequence of the definition of a radical extension.

Comment: We have in a radical extension that $u^n\in K$ for some $n$ how can I be so sure that $u^3\in K$?

Comment: Well degree of$K(x) $ over $K$ is $3$.

Comment: Is there a relation batween the degree of the extension and the $n$ of the $u^n\in K$?

Comment: Usually the $n$ is prime and then we have the degree also equal to $n$. This is because the polynomial $x^n-u^n$ is irreducible over $K$ if $n$ is prime.